# R Web scrape Excel spreadsheet URLs to read with openxlsx

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to read parts of an Excel file into R. I have some existing code, but the authority changed the source. Previously, there was a direct URL to the document, now the link to the document can only be accessed through a website landing page.

Could someone tell me with which package I can achieve that? The link to the Excel file is: http://www.snamretegas.it/it/business-servizi/dati-operativi-business/8_dati_operativi_bilanciamento_sistema/ 
There i am looking at the document: "Dati operativi relativi al bilanciamento del sistema post Del. 312/2016/R/gas - Database 2018"

I add the previous code to give an idea what I did. As you can see, I only required read.xlsx for this first step.

Many thanks in advance!

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(lubridate)
  library(openxlsx)
  library(reshape2)
  library(dplyr)

  Bilres <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx",sheet = "Storico_G", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)


  # Selecting Column R from Storico_G and stored in variable Bilres_df

  Bilres_df <- data.frame(Bilres$pubblicazione, Bilres$BILANCIAMENTO.RESIDUALE )

  # Conerting pubblicazione in date format and time
  Bilres_df$pubblicazione <- ymd_h(Bilres_df$Bilres.pubblicazione)
  Bilreslast=tail(Bilres_df,1)
  Bilreslast=data.frame(Bilreslast)
  Bilreslast$Bilres.BILANCIAMENTO.RESIDUALE <- as.numeric(as.character((Bilreslast$Bilres.BILANCIAMENTO.RESIDUALE)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you copy the URL from the web page, you can then use `download.files()` first to download as a binary file and use `read.xlsx()` to read the data. Depending on how frequently the content changes on the web page, you may be better off just copying the URL than parsing it from the page.

```
oldFile <- "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx"
newFile <- "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/it/business-servizi/dati-operativi-business/dati_operativi_bilanciamento_sistema/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx"

if(!file.exists("./data/downloadedXlsx.xlsx")){
     download.file(newFile,"./data/downloadedXlsx.xlsx",
                   method="curl", #use "curl" for OS X / Linux, "wininet" for Windows
                   mode="wb") # "wb" means "write binary"

} else message("file already loaded locally, using disk version")

library(openxlsx)
Bilres <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "./data/downloadedXlsx.xlsx",
                sheet = "Storico_G", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)
head(Bilres[,1:3])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(Bilres[,1:3])
  pubblicazione aggiornato.il IMMESSO
1 2017_01_01_06      42736.24 1915484
2 2017_01_01_07      42736.28 1915484
3 2017_01_01_08      42736.33 1866326
4 2017_01_01_09      42736.36 1866326
5 2017_01_01_10      42736.41 1866326
6 2017_01_01_11      42736.46 1866326
>
```

**UPDATE:** Added logic to avoid downloading the file once it has been downloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had no idea that you could simple copy the URL (Doooh).

Answer (score 4):

You can find the `.xlsx` links this way:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

pg <- read_html("http://www.snamretegas.it/it/business-servizi/dati-operativi-business/8_dati_operativi_bilanciamento_sistema/")

# get all the Excel (xlsx) links on that page:

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//a[contains(@href, '.xlsx')]") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  sprintf("http://www.snamretegas.it%s", .) -> excel_links

head(excel_links)
## [1] "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/it/business-servizi/dati-operativi-business/dati_operativi_bilanciamento_sistema/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx"
## [2] "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/it/business-servizi/dati-operativi-business/dati_operativi_bilanciamento_sistema/2018/DatiOperativi_2018-IT.xlsx"
```

And, pass in what you want to your Excel reading function:

```
openxlsx::read.xlsx(excel_links[1], sheet = "Storico_G", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)
## data frame output here that I'm not going to show
```

**BUT!!**

This is a very selfish and unkind way to do this since you hit that site for the Excel file **every time** you want to read it, wasting their CPU and bandwidth and your bandwidth.

You should use the `download.file()` technique Len described to cache a local copy and only re-download when necessary.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - Agreed regarding your point about not downloading the same file repeatedly. I added some logic to my answer illustrating how to avoid multiple downloads by checking whether the spreadsheet already exists on disk.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction.

```
library(data.table)
mydat <- fread('http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx')
head(mydat)
```