# Download all excel files from a webpage to R dataframes

Tags: r, web-scraping, download

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790052/download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website). I want to download all Excel files (.xlsx) from [this webpage](https://www.fondbolagen.se/fakta_index/statistik/). But the difference is (I think) that I do not have the same pattern as used in the example. I have tried several variations with no result. Any idea how to download these files? Also, if you can show how I can download them directly into a dataframe (without downloading them to my PC first) that would be appreciated.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095704/r-web-scrape-excel-spreadsheet-urls-to-read-with-openxlsx#48096836) shows how to get the download links. Note some of the files are `.xls` so you may want to change the relevant bit to `contains(@href, '.xls')`

Comment: You say *"all Excel files"*  but there are .xlsx and .xls files in that page. Do you want both?

Comment: Yes please, I would like both! //Rosie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to download the excel files, one step at a time.

First, get the links.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.fondbolagen.se/fakta_index/statistik/"

read_html(url) |>
  html_elements("p") |>
  html_elements("a") |>
  html_attr("href") |>
  (\(x) grep("\\.xls", x, value = TRUE))() |>
  (\(x) sprintf("http://www.fondbolagen.se%s", x))() -> excel_links
```

Now, use the code in [this Rich Scriven post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790793/8245406) to download the files. I have omitted the files creation instruction.

```
dir.create("myexcel")
## save the current directory path for later
wd <- getwd()
## change working directory for the download
setwd("myexcel")
## download them all
lapply(excel_links, \(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
## reset working directory to original
setwd(wd)
```

Comment: Hi! I've been trying to work with your code however I can't seem to figure out what the " |> " does in the first chunk above? Are they supposed to be " %>% " ? Also, R doesn't seem to like that there is a backslash before the x-in-parentheses in two places in the first chunk. Perhaps I'm having problems since I'm using a mac?

Comment: @Rosie No, it's a pipe like `%>%` but in base R since R4.1.0. If your version of R is older, use magrittr's `%<%`.

Comment: Thanks! Also, just wondering, don't know if you saw this above since I was editing the comment: R doesn't seem to like that there is a backslash before the x-in-parentheses in two places in the first chunk. Perhaps I'm having problems since I'm using a mac?

Comment: @Rosie OK, those are 2 new features introduced in R 4.1.0. The `\(x)` is the new lambda, if your version of R is not liking it, replace by the equivalent `function(x)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the further guidance in the comments. Problem solved!