# Identify all excel files from a webpage with Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

mi problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237452/download-all-excel-files-from-a-webpage-to-r-dataframes). I want to identify all excel files in  [this](https://www.portaltransparencia.cl/PortalPdT/directorio-de-organismos-regulados/?org=UN007)
website so I can then download them using download.file.  I have tried several variations with no result, and I think this relates to the use of html_elements and html_attr. For some reason, when trying to select the specific links using the following code excel_links is empty:

```
url <- "https://www.portaltransparencia.cl/PortalPdT/directorio-de-organismos-regulados/?org=UN007"

    read_html(url) |> 
    html_elements("a") |>  
    html_attr(href)) -> excel_links
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Bests,
Maria

Comment: What links are you expecting to be returned from that site specifically? None of the URLs seem to actually point excel files (files that end in xls or xlsx). If you can't tell from the URL alone, it will be trickier to figure it out.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to find the underlying links for each of the months. If you right click on "Enero"(January) and inspect the file to see the HTML you'll see the URLs ending in .xls

Comment: I don't see a link named "Enero" on that page. Did you have to log in or something?

Comment: Ok, I now see what might be happening. If you go to: 04. Personal y remuneraciones: Personal a Contrata > Remuneraciones 2014 you'll find Enero and all the other months. What's interesting is that the URL does not change, so when I try to look for .xls in the HTML code, of course it does not find anything. Does anyone know how to deal with webpages like this?

Comment: I think you will need `RSelenium` for this task, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the detail in the comments it seems you want the Excel files from within "04. Personal y remuneraciones".

The folders housing the Excel files are public facing and so you can simply use the parent folder URI, extract the links for the child year folders, then from those extract the Excel file links.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

year_folder <- "https://transparencia.uv.cl/documentos/personal/remuneraciones/contrata/"

extract_links <- function(parent_link, css_selector_list) {
  links <- read_html(parent_link) %>%
    html_elements(css_selector_list) %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    paste0(parent_link, .)
  return(links)
}

folders_by_year <- extract_links(year_folder, 'li [href$="/"]:not([href^="/"])')

excel_files <- lapply(folders_by_year, extract_links, 'li [href$=".xls"]')
```