# Webscraping using Rvest for wrapped tables

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73223979/identify-all-excel-files-from-a-webpage-with-rvest?noredirect=1#comment129320160_73223979). I want to download the tables for all years/months in this [webpage](https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/planta/2019/Enero/). I have been able to download the tables that appear when opening the website using the following code:

```
#######
# Pages 
#######
yr.list <- seq(2012,2020)
mes.list <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")
c.list <- c("contrata","planta")

################################################
## UTarapaca Scraping Loop PLANTA & CONTRATA
################################################

combined_df <- data.frame()
for (c in c.list){
for (yr in yr.list){
  for (mes in mes.list) {
      # UChile URL
      root <- "https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/"
      
      # Full link    
      url <- paste(root,c,"/",yr,"/",mes,"/",sep="")
      
      # Parse HTML File
      file<-read_html(url)
      
      # Get the nodes were the tables live
      tables<-html_nodes(file, "table")
      
      # This is the relevant table
      table <- as.data.frame(html_table(tables[1], fill = TRUE))
    }
```

Nonetheless, that code only fetches the 10 registers from the first page (Registros por pagina = 10 in the upper right corner of the table) and what I want is to download all the registers that the wrapped table contains. I tried looping over the different "table pages" (see lower right corner of the table to see pages) but the URL does not change when changing the page.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Bests,
Maria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way with `rvest`. First create all links outside any loop. Then `lapply` an anonymous function to read each page and extract the tables from those pages.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

root <- "https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/"
c.list <- c("contrata","planta")
yr.list <- seq(2012, 2020)
mes.list <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")

df_links <- expand.grid(c.list, yr.list, mes.list)
head(df_links)

links <- with(df_links, sprintf("%s%s/%s/%s", root, Var1, Var2, Var3))
length(links)

tables_list <- lapply(links, \(x) {
  page <- read_html(x)
  tbl_list <- page %>%
    html_elements("table") %>%
    html_children() %>%
    html_table()
  names(tbl_list[[2]]) <- names(tbl_list[[1]])
  tbl_list[[2]]
})
```

---

## Edit

To create a column with the combination c/mes/year, use the following `lapply` loop.

```
tables_list <- lapply(seq_along(links), \(i) {
  x <- links[i]
  id <- with(df_links, sprintf("%s/%s/%s", Var1[i], Var3[i], Var2[i]))
  page <- read_html(x)
  tbl_list <- page %>%
    html_elements("table") %>%
    html_children() %>%
    html_table()
  names(tbl_list[[2]]) <- names(tbl_list[[1]])
  tbl_list[[2]]$id <- id
  tbl_list[[2]]
})

unique(unlist(sapply(tables_list, '[[', 'id')))
#> [1] "contrata/Enero/2012" "planta/Enero/2012"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Would it be possible to add a column with the combination of c/mes/year to know the origin of each table? How would you do that?

Comment: @MariaPalma Done, see the edit.

Comment: Hi again @Rui, I am trying to do this again on a very similar webpage: [link](https://transparencia.uda.cl/index.php?view=UDA-T17.19_12). I already know how to get all the links, but when I try to run the tables_list bit I get the following error: "Warning messages:
1: The `value` argument of `names<-` must have the same length as `x` as of tibble 3.0.0.
`names` must have length 17, not 14. 
2: The `value` argument of `names<-` can't be empty as of tibble 3.0.0.
Columns 15, 16, and 17 must be named."  and I am not sure why. Have you got any ideas on why this may be happening?? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Libraries and data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

df <- expand.grid(
  yr.list = seq(2012, 2020),
  mes.list = c(
    "Enero",
    "Febrero",
    "Marzo",
    "Abril",
    "Mayo",
    "Junio",
    "Julio",
    "Agosto",
    "Septiembre",
    "Octubre",
    "Noviembre",
    "Diciembre"
  ),
  c.list = c("contrata", "planta")
) %>%
  mutate(links = paste0(
    "https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/",
    c.list,
    "/",
    yr.list,
    "/",
    mes.list
  )) %>% 
  as_tibble
```

Define a function to get the table and report it in a nested data

```
get_data <- function(link) {
  link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table() %>%
    getElement(1) %>%
    janitor::clean_names()
}

final_df <- df %>%
  slice(1:5) %>% 
  mutate(content = map(links, get_data))

# A tibble: 5 × 5
  yr.list mes.list c.list   links                                          content 
    <int> <fct>    <fct>    <chr>                                          <list>  
1    2012 Enero    contrata https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/contrata/201… <tibble>
2    2013 Enero    contrata https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/contrata/201… <tibble>
3    2014 Enero    contrata https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/contrata/201… <tibble>
4    2015 Enero    contrata https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/contrata/201… <tibble>
5    2016 Enero    contrata https://www.uta.cl/transparencia/contrata/201… <tibble>
```

Unnest and view it

```
# A tibble: 1,614 × 25
   yr.list mes.list c.list   apellido_paterno apellido_materno nombres    estamento
     <int> <fct>    <fct>    <chr>            <chr>            <chr>      <chr>    
 1    2012 Enero    contrata ACEVEDO          UBILLA           CHARLIE E… TECNICO  
 2    2012 Enero    contrata AGUAYO           BURDILES         CRISTIAN … AUXILIAR 
 3    2012 Enero    contrata AGUIRRE          POLLAROLO        TERESA DE… ACADEMICO
 4    2012 Enero    contrata ALARCON          HERRERA          JUAN FRAN… AUXILIAR 
 5    2012 Enero    contrata ALARCON          MENESES          LUIS MANU… PROFESIO…
 6    2012 Enero    contrata ALEGRE           OSSANDON         DANIEL     AUXILIAR 
 7    2012 Enero    contrata ALFONSO          GAJARDO          JORGE CRI… ADMINIST…
 8    2012 Enero    contrata ALFRED           URIZAR           MARIA CRI… ACADEMICO
 9    2012 Enero    contrata ALVAREZ          FLORES           KAREN      PROFESIO…
10    2012 Enero    contrata ALVEAL           FUENTES          CLAUDIA    ADMINIST…
# … with 1,604 more rows, and 18 more variables: grado_erut <chr>, bienios <chr>,
#   jerarquia_academica <chr>, jornada <chr>,
#   calificacion_profesional_o_formacion <chr>, cargo_o_funcion <chr>,
#   region <chr>, asignaciones_especiales <chr>, haberes_transitorios <chr>,
#   remuneracion_bruta_segun_grado <chr>, renta_bruta_mensualizada <chr>,
#   unidad_monetaria <chr>, horas_extraordinarias <chr>, fecha_inicio <chr>,
#   fecha_termino <chr>, observaciones <chr>, …
```