# Webscraping does not identify the full HTML link

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

My problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73223979/identify-all-excel-files-from-a-webpage-with-rvest?noredirect=1#comment129320160_73223979) one. I want to identify all the HTML links in [this](http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_fecha&ig=21) website so I can then open the link and download the tables.
The problem is that when I create the extract_links functions as pointed out in that answer, I get a list of all the HTMLs, but this are not complete.

To make it more clear:
If you press "Junio" in year "2022" the real HTML is the following:

```
http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_generar_plantilla&ig=21&m=6&a=2022&ia=7658
```

but the HTML that I am recovering from the source of the website lacks the last bit (&ia=7658):

```
http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_generar_plantilla&ig=21&m=6&a=2022
```

Which does not direct me to the table I want.

The problem is that these numbers do not seem to follow any logic and change between year/month links. Any help on how to retrieve the full HTML links will be greatly appreciated. If you also happen to know how can I retrieve the year/month of the file to add as an extra column that would also be great.

Thanks to the help of @margusl I was able to realize that rvest redirects automatically and that solves my problem.

I am trying to use the following code to loop over different links to obtain the tables, store them in a data frame and then download them:

```
yr.list <- seq(2019,2020)
mes.list <- seq(1,12)

combined_df <- data.frame()

for (yr in yr.list){
  for (mes in mes.list) {
      root <- "http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21"
      
      # Full link    
      url <- paste(root,"&m=",mes,"&a=",yr,sep="")
      
      # Parse HTML File
      file<-read_html(url, encoding = "latin1") 
      file<- rvest::html_table(file)
      str(file)
      
      # This is the relevant table
      table <- as.data.frame(file[[1]])
      
    
      # in your loop, add the files that you read to the combined_df
      combined_df <- rbind(combined_df, table)  
    }
}
```

It does not work because the read_html code with the encoding works only for some years, but not for all. for example, when running:

```
 url <- "http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=3&a=2015"
  file<-read_html(url, encoding = "latin1")
```

It does not recover the tables with names/surnames that recovers in the previous months but something else. Why can't this work on all the sub-pages? Is this a encoding problem again?

Comment: Links you get from the page are "real", those are the same URLs your browser requests. Though it gets redirected to address you see on a address bar and it can take about 20 .. 30 seconds to handle redirection and loading the target page.  As rvest (at least rvest 1.0.3 / R 4.2.1 ) seems to handle redirects just fine, you should be all set.

Comment: Scraping is spelled s-c-r-a-p-i-n-g

Comment: @margusl thanks for your answer. If I am getting the real link, then I am not sure why it is not working when trying to find the table using  read_html and html_nodes.  Could you please help me?

Comment: Also, @Rob I do not appreciate your irony.

Comment: Not sure if I got that right, but final URLs are not present on your page.  Open http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_fecha&ig=21 in your brwser, copy any of those links (left click, copy link address), open new page or tab and paste it to address bar and press enter, wait for 10..20seconds to see how it changes. That's redirection.

Comment: For me `rvest::read_html("http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=6&a=2022") |> rvest::html_table()` returns list of tables, same ones that I see on `http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_generar_plantilla&ig=21&m=6&a=2022&ia=7658` . Though it takes time, 10+ seconds. Please consider adding the code you already have to the question.

Comment: Hi again @margusl. For that year & month, it works to do: `rvest::read_html("http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=6&a=2022") |> rvest::html_table() ` and then use as.data.frame to convert. But that does not work when using other months/years. (I have tried "http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=1&a=2021" and it does not return the table I want.

Comment: Some of those target pages seem to have some kind of encoding issue, try adding `encoding = "latin1"` to `read_html()`, i.e. for your last link it should read:    `rvest::read_html("http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=1&a=2021", encoding = "latin1") |> rvest::html_table()`

Comment: It's not irony. It's a spelling correction you need to be aware of. Scrapping is something entirely different from scraping.

Comment: Hi @margusl , adding the encoding bit does not help. The commands are not capturing the table with relevant data, but some other things in the webpage. Is it working for you? When using those commands, can you recover the actual table in that link?

Comment: I can get those same tables I see in browser - https://gist.github.com/marguslt/c4ab0e478514be53f872651736613ce5 - though I have no way telling of telling if those are the same ones you expect.

Comment: Thus I strongly encourage you to edit your question and include your existing code, it should form a repeatable example so others can just copy-paste and execute it as-is, i.e include all libraries and defined objects. And please be really specific about the output you do get and output you expect ( linking would not really do, sites my serve some content depending our geolocation or browser settings)

Comment: Hi @margusl , I already did. I am managing to recover most of the tables thanks to your help, but some remain a problem. Could you please see it? Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 0):

If you open that last page you had issues with, you'll see that it serves a sort of a submenu with 2 more links - http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=3&a=2015 . Meaning that it's not enough to just generate links for each month & year and extract first table of each page, all those pages should be checked for content and exceptions should be handled.

Though I took somewhat opportunistic approach and it happened to work with URL range defined in question + those few odd samples, but there could be other surprises down the road. Switched to `httr` for making requests as it allows to collect and monitor response headers, separating content retrieval and parsing also seems to work around encoding issues, at least in this case. First collecting and then parsing also simplifies debugging, you can check if certain responses / headers were different from the rest (i.e. response length being 10x smaller than average or final, redirected, url differs from the rest). And it's easy to change content handling
/ parsing for a small subset of responses, if needed. If you are not sure what rvest has retrieved, you can always save the response to a html file and check it with browser or editor, something like
`html <- read_html(url_or_text_content); write(as.character(html), "dump.html")`

```r
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

yr.list <- seq(2019,2020)
mes.list <- seq(1,12)

# combine mes.list & yr.list
url.params <- expand.grid(mes = mes.list, yr = yr.list)
# few extra samples:
url.params <- rbind(url.params, 
        list(mes = 6, yr = 2022), # here rvest strugglest with correct encoding
        list(mes = 3, yr = 2015)  # returns page with sub-categories 
        )

url.list <- str_glue("http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m={url.params$mes}&a={url.params$yr}")
url.list
#> http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=1&a=2019
#> http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=2&a=2019
#> http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=3&a=2019
#> ...
#> http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=11&a=2020
#> http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=12&a=2020
#> http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=6&a=2022
#> http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=3&a=2015

# url list for input, output is a tibble with all responses (incl. "url", "date", 
# "status_code", header details and response body)
fetch_urls <- function(url.list){
  # collect all responses to a list with httr, enable verbose, parse responses later
  # add progress bar - requests take a while
  resp.list = vector(mode = "list", length = length(url.list))
  pb <- txtProgressBar(max = length(url.list), style = 3)
  for (i in seq_along(url.list)){
    resp.list[[i]] <- GET(url.list[i])
    setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
  }
  close(pb)
  
  # turn responses into tibble to check urls, response sizes and status codes
  resp.tibble <- bind_cols(
    map_df(resp.list, ~ .[c("url", "date", "status_code")], .id = "req_id"), 
    map_df(resp.list, headers) %>% rename_with(~ paste0("header_",.x)),
    # map_df(resp_follow.list, "times"),
    map_chr(resp.list, content, as = "text") %>% tibble(html_doc = .)
  )
  return(resp.tibble)
}

resp.tibble <- fetch_urls(url.list)
# check resulting table without html_doc column
# View(resp.tibble[-ncol(resp.tibble)])

resp.tibble %>% 
  select(req_id:status_code,`header_content-length`) %>% 
  arrange(`header_content-length`)
#> # A tibble: 26 × 5
#>    req_id url                                date                statu…¹ heade…²
#>    <chr>  <chr>                              <dttm>                <int> <chr>  
#>  1 14     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:29:12     200 21371  
#>  2 26     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:31:45     200 2230   
#>  3 24     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:31:21     200 24035  
#>  4 21     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:30:42     200 24173  
#>  5 20     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:30:29     200 24183  
#>  6 23     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:31:08     200 24184  
#>  7 22     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:30:55     200 24207  
#>  8 18     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:30:04     200 24405  
#>  9 16     http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:29:38     200 24715  
#> 10 7      http://transparencia.uantof.cl/in… 2022-10-31 17:27:32     200 24716  
#> # … with 16 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​status_code,
#> #   ²​`header_content-length`

# 26. is kind of suspicious:
# 25      http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_generar_plantilla&ig=21&m=6&a=2022&ia=76…   
# 26      http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_selec_archivo&ig=21&m=3&a=2015              

# looks like there has been no redirection and its header_content-length is about 10x smaller than for other responses
# checking it more closely reveals that the page includes a "submenu" instead of table(s):
# <p class="subMenu_interiores">
#   <b>2015 - Marzo</b>
#   <a href="index.php?action=plantillas_generar_plantilla&amp;ig=21&amp;m=3&amp;a=2015&amp;ia=772">ABRIL 2015</a>
#   <a href="index.php?action=plantillas_generar_plantilla&amp;ig=21&amp;m=3&amp;a=2015&amp;ia=648">Marzo 2015</a>
# </p>

# lets' collect urls that were not redirected from our tibble and harvest links from stored html:
suburl.list <-  resp.tibble %>% 
  # urls that do NOT include "plantillas_generar_plantilla"
  filter(!str_detect(url, "plantillas_generar_plantilla")) %>% 
  pull(html_doc) %>% 
  # rvest does not like lists, thus let's map()
  map( ~ read_html(.x) %>% html_elements("#columna1_interiores a") %>% html_attr("href")) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  paste0("http://transparencia.uantof.cl/",.)
suburl.list
#> [1] "http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_generar_plantilla&ig=21&m=3&a=2015&ia=772"
#> [2] "http://transparencia.uantof.cl/index.php?action=plantillas_generar_plantilla&ig=21&m=3&a=2015&ia=648"

# fetch content from those submenu urls
subresp.tibble <- fetch_urls(suburl.list)
# sanity check:
subresp.tibble %>% 
  select(req_id:status_code,`header_content-length`)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   req_id url                                 date                statu…¹ heade…²
#>   <chr>  <chr>                               <dttm>                <int> <chr>  
#> 1 1      http://transparencia.uantof.cl/ind… 2022-10-31 17:31:52     200 25385  
#> 2 2      http://transparencia.uantof.cl/ind… 2022-10-31 17:31:59     200 25332  
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​status_code, ²​`header_content-length`

# better, sizes align with previous results.

# collect all relevant responses
table_1 <- resp.tibble %>% 
  filter(str_detect(url, "plantillas_generar_plantilla")) %>% 
  bind_rows(subresp.tibble) %>% 
  # extract html (as strings)
  pull(html_doc) %>% 
  # rvest does not like lists, thus let's map(), pluck(1) extracts first table (from each page)
  map(~ read_html(.x) %>% html_table() %>% pluck(1)) %>% 
  # first attempt to bind rows fails, aparently column types differ
  # change all non-character columns to character
  map (~ mutate(.x, across(!where(is.character),as.character))) %>% 
  # bind all tables by rows
  bind_rows()

# columns vary across tables so number of NA fields in final result is rather high
```

Final result for 26 pages, a 10,987 × 30 tibble:

```r
table_1
#> # A tibble: 10,987 × 30
#>    Nº    PLANTA        PATERNO MATERNO NOMBRES G     TITULO CARGO REGION ASIGN…¹
#>    <chr> <chr>         <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  
#>  1 1     DIRECTIVO     ABARZA  CASTRO  JESSIC… 6     ADMIN… JEFE… SEGUN… (1)(8)…
#>  2 2     PROFESIONAL   ABASOLO QUINTE… NURY D… 12    EDUCA… PROF… SEGUN… (4)(8)…
#>  3 3     ACADEMICO     ACOSTA  PENA    ROXANA… 11    EDUCA… PROF… SEGUN… (2)(8)…
#>  4 4     AUXILIARES    ACOSTA  PIZARRO ROBERT… 23    LICEN… AUXI… SEGUN… (7)(8)…
#>  5 5     DIRECTIVO     AGENO   SIERRA  ROSELL… 4     MATRO… DIRE… SEGUN… (1)(8)…
#>  6 6     AUXILIARES    AGUIRRE LAZO    RENE G… 16    LICEN… AUXI… SEGUN… (7)(8)…
#>  7 7     TECNICOS      ALAMOS  MARIN   SERGIO… 13    TECNI… TECN… SEGUN… (5)(8)…
#>  8 8     AUXILIARES    ALAYANA CORTES  CHRIST… 23    LICEN… AUXI… SEGUN… (7)(8)…
#>  9 9     ACADEMICO     ALCOTA  AGUIRRE PATRIC… 9     ING. … PROF… SEGUN… (2)(8)…
#> 10 10    ADMINISTRATI… ALFARO  BARRAZA MARIA … 23    LICEN… ADMI… SEGUN… (6)(8)…
#> # … with 10,977 more rows, 20 more variables: `UNID MONETARIA` <chr>,
#> #   `REMUNERACION MENSUAL BRUTA` <chr>, HORAS <chr>, `CANT. HORAS` <chr>,
#> #   `MONTO HORAS EXTRAS` <chr>, `FECHA DE INGRESO` <chr>, `F. HASTA` <chr>,
#> #   OBSERVACIONES <chr>, GRADO <chr>, ESTAMENTO <chr>,
#> #   `Apellido Paterno` <chr>, `Apellido Materno` <chr>, Nombres <chr>,
#> #   `Grado ERUA` <chr>, `CALIFICACION PROFESIONAL O FORMACION` <chr>,
#> #   `CARGO O FUNCION` <chr>, `R BRUTA` <chr>, `Horas Extras` <chr>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>